# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7 in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-push-notification

my react-native version "0.61.5" and my xcode version is 11 after I added push-notification-ios[Push Notification ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios) to project I get this error :

```
duplicate symbol '_RCTRemoteNotificationReceived' in:
    .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myprojectname-busrrsxathritwfouhsiiyaolopv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNCPushNotificationIOS/libRNCPushNotificationIOS.a(RNCPushNotificationIOS.o)
    .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myprojectname-busrrsxathritwfouhsiiyaolopv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-RCTPushNotification/libReact-RCTPushNotification.a(RCTPushNotificationManager.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i do this job but get this error :

```
1.clean project
2.claen pod
3.delete pods and install again
```

and this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.16.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "git+https://github.com/harshitjee/react-native-material-dropdown.git",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.6",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-simple-table": "0.0.3",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-table": "^7.0.0-rc.15",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

how to solve this problems? thanks for helping me

**Update:** 
this is Screenshot of the error
[image]
**Update 2:**
this is Screenshot of the build Phases:
[image]

Comment: Did you manually linked the library as well?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your screenshot, I think you should give this step a try

In Xcode -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> remove libRNCPushNotificationIOS.a

then clean, build your project

This should work

Comment: in this rout just I have libPods{project name}.a

Comment: then click + button there in Link Libraries and add libRNCPushNotificationIOS.a

then clean build your project

Comment: I added and clean and build again the same error. and delete again and the same eror.

Comment: Notice your screenshot, it is showing 2 things to be added libRCTPushNotification.a and libRNCPushNotificationIOS.a once you do this, delete derived data and then clean and again build the project.

Comment: But why are you using both libRNCPushNotificationIOS and libRCTPushNotification? Remove one of them from package and then install node module and all other steps. I guess this both libraries are conflicting

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that "_RCTRemoteNotificationReceived" this library or package is linked more than one time,

react-native unlink

try **deleting node modules**

Follow this steps:-

- yarn install
- cd ios
- pod install
- cd ..
- react-native link

then run your project again but before following all of this delete derived data.

Comment: @AmirFarahani can you show the screenshot of whole error?

Comment: i added screenshot @RB RB

Comment: @AmirFarahani I have posted another answer please check it.

Comment: You don’t need to run react native link since RN 0.60 and above supports auto linking.